# Why does Mathematica give no output in DSolve equation?

Tags: differential-equations

I was trying to solve this differential equation, but the mathematica gave me the same equation for output.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
DSolve[{y''[t]*m == g*m - 1/2 (y'[t])^2*\[Rho][y[t]]*Cd[y'[t]]*A, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0}, y[t], t]
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: `Cd[y]` and `ρ[y]` are not functions known to *Mathematica*, so it doesn't know what to do, and just echoes your input.

Comment: And even if you remove rho and Cd functions which are not defined, `DSolve` can't solve it due to non-linearity. `DSolve[{y''[t]*m == g*m - 1/2 (y'[t])^2*y[t]*y'[t]*A, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0}, y[t], t]`. And even if you give numerical values to the parameters, it can't do it `m = 1;
g = 98/10;
A = 5;
DSolve[{y''[t]*m == g*m - 1/2 (y'[t])^2*y[t]*y'[t]*A}, y[t], t]`. May be you can try numerical solutions. Numerical always works on anything. Well almost anything.

Comment: @Nasser  Interestingly, setting `g = 0` and ignoring the initial conditions allows `DSolve` to obtain a solution.

Comment: @bbgodfrey good finding. This means it could not find particular solution but can only find find homogenous solution. This works `DSolve[y''[t] + (y'[t])^2*y[t]*y'[t] == 0, y[t], t]`  but not this `DSolve[y''[t] + (y'[t])^2*y[t]*y'[t] == 1, y[t], t]`

Comment: @Nasser  `y''[t] + (y'[t])^2*y[t]*y'[t] == 0` has the first integral, `-1/y'[t] + y[t]^2/2 == c`.  First integrals probably exist for most choices of `Cd[y'[t]]` and `ρ[y[t]]`, although perhaps not for complete solutions to the ODE.  A Mathematica function  to compute first integrals would be helpful.  Now that I think about it, the ODE can be reduced to first order even for `g != 0`, because `t` does not occur explicitly (i.e, the ODE is autonomous).